# Using COUNT with CASE, how do I order resulting columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have the following code:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Title LIKE '%Superintendent%' THEN 1 END) AS 'Bob',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Title LIKE '%Machine%' THEN 1 END) AS 'Control',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Title LIKE '%Estimator%' THEN 1 END) AS 'Estimator'
FROM pants;
```

Current result looks like this:

```
Bob   Control   Estimator
230   550       1243
```

Instead, I would like the resulting view from the query to have the columns in descending order: Estimator --> Control --> Bob

Comment: Please explain what "descending order" means.  Sample data can really help.

Comment: The result is a number (hence the count select statement above) in each column. I want those columns to be ranked in descending order of those counted values

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to mess around dynamically with the order of columns in the result set. The query should, instead, have a result set with a highly predictable (ideally static) set of columns.

To re-order the columns is, I'd recommend, the job of whatever *renders* that result set after the database returns it.

Answer (score 1):

SQLs sorting is designed to order rows, not columns. In order to change the column order in your output, you would need to order your data, then build a dynamic query to return the columns in the right order. However, it is a lot easier just to do the first part (ordering your data) if a result like this would be acceptable for what you need.

```
Name       Total
Estimator  1243
Control    550
Bob        230
```

This query could look something like this (my MySQL syntax is rusty, but this should be close)

```
SELECT 'Bob' as Name, COUNT(CASE WHEN Title LIKE '%Superintendent%' THEN 1 END) AS Total From Pants
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Control' as Name, COUNT(CASE WHEN Title LIKE '%Machine%' THEN 1 END) AS Total From Pants
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Estimator' as Name, COUNT(CASE WHEN Title LIKE '%Estimator%' THEN 1 END) AS Total From Pants
ORDER BY Total desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
; 
WITH cte AS 
( 
       SELECT dtls, 
              pantcounts 
       FROM   ( 
                     SELECT Count( 
                            CASE 
                                   WHEN title LIKE '%Superintendent%' THEN 1 
                            END) AS 'Bob', 
                            Count( 
                            CASE 
                                   WHEN title LIKE '%Machine%' THEN 1 
                            END) AS 'Control', 
                            Count( 
                            CASE 
                                   WHEN title LIKE '%Estimator%' THEN 1 
                            END) AS 'Estimator' 
                     FROM   pants) P UNPIVOT (pantcounts FOR dtls IN (bob, 
                                                                      [Control], 
                                                                      [Estimator])) AS unp 
       select   dtls, 
                pantcounts, 
                row_number() OVER (ORDER BY pantcounts DESC) AS rownum 
       FROM     cte
```

This will give the required sorted data in row. Then service layer should do the transpose from rows to column.